# JSON object from store in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Can we get JSON object from store in sencha?
Please provide useful links or working code or Some explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the store object to JSON  use `Ext.encode(datastore.data)`